# GeneratorExit exception: no description

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) and [BS4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) modules, with placed breakpoints, it often throws an exception (or even more than one) on the lines where the `request.get` and `bs4.BeautifulSoup` located. Without setting breakpoints, there are no errors.

```
def func_a(link):
    request = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
    soup = soup.find('a', {'class': 'mva_item'})
    result = soup['href']
    return result
```

Do such exceptions affect the execution time of the program?

Comment: This is very vague. Provide some code and more detail.

Comment: @AlexHall added some code

Comment: What do you mean "with placed breakpoints, it often throws an exception...Without setting breakpoints, there are no errors". Is this in a debugger? Which debugger? What exactly does it show?

Comment: @AlexHall VS code, while you press F9 it sets breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should only worry about performance where you have specifically observed a problem. If you can show that these exceptions are slowing down your program to a level you are not satisfied with, you can consider doing something about it. I doubt it's a problem. Your code has to fetch information from the Internet, no optimisation will change that. If they were slowing things down, you could probably do nothing about it anyway.